# convert char array elemnts to upper or lower case

Tags: c, arrays, char

For my homework assignment we are asked to get a string from the user and:

1. convert it all to uppercase = completed
2. convert it all to lowercase = completed
3. convert the each character if it is upper to lower and vice versa. (problem)

I do not know if my logic is wrong or if it's a simple fix. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
int i;
char sentense [30];
printf("Please enter a sentence\n");
fgets(sentense, 30, stdin);

for(i=0; sentense[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    putchar(toupper(sentense[i]));
}

for(i=0; sentense[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    putchar(tolower(sentense[i]));
}

for(i=0; sentense[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if(sentense[i] >='65' && sentense[i] <='90')
    {
        putchar(tolower(sentense[i]));
    }


    else if(sentense[i] >= '97' && sentense[i] <='122')
    {
        putchar(tolower(sentense[i]));
    }
    else
    {

    }
}



return 0;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add, in step 3, its just prints out the word/sentence entered all in lowercase

Comment: You shouldn't use "magic numbers", that's very poor programming practice. So instead of 65, use `'A'`.

Comment: if you #include <ctype.h> then you can greatly simplify the code by using the functions: `isupper()` and `islower()` and `isalpha()`   This header file is also needed for the `toupper()` and `tolower()` functions

Comment: When compiling, always enable all the warnings (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )  Then the compiler will tell you about the many problems with the posted code.  Fix those problems, do not ignore them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change

```
if(sentense[i] >='65' && sentense[i] <='90')
```

to

```
if(sentense[i] >= 65 && sentense[i] <= 90)
```

and rest case(s) as we want to compare the integer value here.

Enable the compiler warning and your compiler should be warning you about the mistake.

Alternatively, you can also make use of [`isupper()`/`islower()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isupper) library functions, too.

Comment: @rissandimo click a check mark under the down vote arrow to confirm that this is best answer

Answer (score 4):

- you should use `isupper` and `islower` to prevent the code to depend on character codes.
- you should use `toupper` instead of `tolower` to convert letters to uppercase.
- you may have to print characters other than English alphabets.

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main()
{
    int i;
    char sentense [30];
    printf("Please enter a sentence\n");
    fgets(sentense, 30, stdin);

    for(i=0; sentense[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        putchar(toupper(sentense[i]));
    }

    for(i=0; sentense[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        putchar(tolower(sentense[i]));
    }

    for(i=0; sentense[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(isupper(sentense[i]))
        {
            putchar(tolower(sentense[i]));
        }


        else if(islower(sentense[i]))
        {
            putchar(toupper(sentense[i]));
        }
        else
        {
            putchar(sentense[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `tolower` won't convert to uppercase, but @rissandimo used `tolower` in where the input should be converted to uppercase. that was not good.

Answer (score 2):

Easy to understand, you should compare directly. Let's use:

```
if(sentense[i] >='A' && sentense[i] <='Z')
```

to check the up-case. And use:

```
if(sentense[i] >='a' && sentense[i] <='z')
```

to check the low-case.